# IBM Cloud: Clicking "View ticket", got "Error 500: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d"

Tags: browser, ibm-cloud

It is terrible. 
When I wanted to check Ticket Status, I clicked "View Ticket" on IBM Cloud, then I got stuck. Response is "Error 500: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d". I tried other browsers such as Chrome, Safari, Edge.But same issue happened.

I looked for solution for this issue. But I didn't find any good way. Could you help to solve terrible issue?
Thanks

Comment: I guess none of your own code is involved here? If so, this is an all internal code bug on a 3rd party service. I recommend to, well, raise another ticket to their help desk. If I am mistaken, and it is a problem with your code, then you have to provide a [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: @GhostCat Here is no my code. It seems to be due to internal code bug on IBM Cloud. I've raised a ticket for this issue. But I can't see ticket status due to this issue. Thank you for your reply. I'm literary true beginner of stackoverflow.